# Kusto - format numbers with 1000 comma separator

Tags: kql

I have numerical output from a Kusto/KQL query where I would like to format the output to have comma separations. I would also like to round to the nearest whole number. For instance, instead of `1000.2865` it would come out as `1,000`. Is there any built-in KQL function to accomplish this? I checked the documentation but couldn't find it. I would hope to find something like this:

```
format_number(myNumberColumn, 0, "commaThousands")
```

Note: if it comes out as a string I'm fine with that, and I also realize the displayed output in Azure Data Explorer does visually format. But once I take the data outside of there I lose that formatting, like if I paste into Excel or use the query for a dashboard to show a key metric.

Answer (score 1):

1. for rounding a number, you can use the [`round()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/roundfunction), the [`ceiling()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ceilingfunction), the [`floor()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/floorfunction), or the [`toint()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/tointfunction).
2. formatting numbers, e.g. adding separating commas, would be best if done by the client application you're using to present the result (e.g. you mentioned Excel, which certainly has this feature for formatting numeric values in cells).